# Realm Studio - Durability not consistent

Tags: flutter, realm, realm-studio

When I open the default.realm file for a flutter app that is currently running on an iOS simulator, I get the messages "Durability not consistent" and "No schema selected". Is there any solution to this? [image]

Note: I'm running flutter 3.16.9, Realm Studio 14.1.2.41 & am using the realm: ^1.6.0 flutter plugin

Comment: Try closing the flutter app first and then open with Realm Studio.  I don't believe Realm Studio supports multiprocess access of synced Realms. I'm pretty sure that's in progress though. Report back your findings. If it still doesn't work, there's a get report that ti was fixed so that should be flagged [#1594](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/pull/1594)

Comment: I had tried that before, but it didn't work either. It turns out the reason was because I was using an inMemory db instead of a local db.

Answer (score 0):

The Realm instance needs to be set up with `Realm(Configuration.local...` instead of `Realm(Configuration.inMemory...` Reading the realm file for an in memory database is apparently not currently supported.